# Need help writing a function to get the minimum and maximum temperatures for each city in C

Tags: c

The question, in particular, is: "Write a C program to accept the average yearly temperature of the past five years, for five cities. Display the maximum and minimum temperature for each city. Use functions to determine the maximum and minimum temperatures."
I have no problem with writing the code for input, but I can't write the function to get the right min and max values. This is what I've got so far (I'm practicing with pointers, so I mostly use pointers in my code):

```
void getMinMax(int *t)
{
    int i = 0, min = 0, max = 0;
    min = max = *t;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if(min > *(t + i))
        {
            min = *(t + i);
        }

        if(max < *(t + i))
        {
            max = *(t + i);
        }
    }

    printf("Min: %d\nMax: %d\n", min, max);
}   

void main()
{
    char *city[5];
    int *temps, i = 0, j = 0;
    int min = 0, max = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        city[i] = (char*)malloc(50);
    }

    temps = (int*)malloc(25 * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter city: ");
        scanf("%s", city[i]);
        printf("Yearly temperatures of city %d:\n", i + 1);

        for(j = i * 5; j < (i * 5) + 5; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",temps + j);
        }

        getMinMax(temps);
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Enter city: A
1
2
3
4
5
Min: 1
Max: 5
Enter city: B
2
3
4
5
6
Min: 1
Max: 5
```

The min and max values are always the same for every city, I can't figure out where I did wrong.

Comment: Don't do `*(t + i)` to access arrays, just do `t[i]`.

Comment: As said above, use the array notation for the pointer, it's way more readable.
And _free the pointers_, a free for every malloc.

In this case you will see nothing as it's the main function and the operative system will clean the memory after the process ands, but it's still a memory leak to me.

Then, since it looks like a school stuff let's ask some less related questions: 

- Are you using an IDE? it's time to use a debugger too. 
- Have you ever heard of Valgrind? Valgrind is you best friend when you don't use managed pointers.

Comment: @TomKarzes Good point, fixed.

Comment: @VincenzoLaSpesa Yes this is an assignment, I'm currently learning C and using Embarcadero Dev-C++ as IDE. My teacher talked about using the built-in debugger but I didn't pay attention, I think it's time I learn how to use it.

Comment: @HiếuVi sure, Borland Debugger is very easy to understand, it was my first IDE too back in school. Give it a try, the step by step execution usually makes you see a lot of details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in this line:

```
         getMinMax(temps);
```

Every time you are sending the same address in getMinMax function, i.e. the first address or temp[0], so every time you are getting the same result. So you have to update the address that is being sent within getMinMax. Just do the following:

```
         getMinMax(temps+ (i*5));
```

It will update the starting address for each city, and it will work fine

Comment: Thank you it really works. I didn't think about it when passing arguments into a function before.

Answer (score 1):

When you call

```
getMinMax(temps);
```

you pass a pointer to the *first* element of `temps`. Then you use only the first five elements inside the function.

You need to pass a pointer to the first elements of the current city which is `&temps[i * 5]`.

---

With that said, why don't you use an array of arrays for *both* city names and the temperatures? As in

```
char city[5][50];
int temps[5][5];
```

That will make much of your code simpler.

Comment: Thank you, your answer works the same way as Ankush's, I didn't remember the addresses/elements changes when passing arguments. As I stated in my question, I'm currently practicing with pointers, so I used pointers instead of arrays.